# how to draw a rectangle in an image using open cv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to draw a rectangle in an image using open cv c++?I read a function called CV::rectangle,can anyone explain how this function works?Or is there any other method which can be used to draw rectangle?

Comment: [docs are your friend!](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can use [cv::rectangle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle).

You should be able to draw something using this code

```
cv::rectangle( img, cv::Point2f( 10, 10 ), cv::Point2f(100, 100), cv::Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ) );
```

This will draw a red rectangle starting with top left at (10, 10) and bottom right at (100,100).

This also assumes that img has 3 channels of usigned int type, if the type is different, then you need to change the values in the Scalar.

Comment: `cv::Scalar( 255, 0, 0 )` // BLUE: color ordering as BGR.  But +1 for sharing this bit of code!